# How can i insert custom tracking url in Order confirmation Email Template?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, template, email-templates, order-email

I want to insert my custom tracking url in Order Confirmation email and url is
https://vitalticks.shiprocket.co
i put code like this

Track you Order here:[Vitalticks Order Tracking Page](https://vitalticks.shiprocket.co)

But it is not redirecting to the custom url.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be pretty simple,

The default e-mail template that is sent by Magento is:

1. Customer: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html
2. Guest: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new_guest.html

**You must not edit those files directly on vendor. They can be loaded on admin panel:**

1. Marketing > Communications > Email Templates;
2. Click on "Add New Template" button;
3. Load the default template (Order or Order Guest);
   [image: Load default template]
4. Include a title for the new template;
5. Include the link on the shipment section;
   [image: Include the link on the shipment section]
6. Save the template;
7. Go to Stores > Settings > Configuration and then Sales > Sales Emails
8. On the order section you must deselect the option `Use system value` and then choose the template that you have created.
   [image]